# $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); with title not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use bootstrap-select and laravel 7 to improve the style of one my projects but when the options of the select are built dynamically the plugin does not work and I do not find the error. I have included the `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');` as proposed by this answer but still I am not able to achieve what I want. The HTML is the following and works perfectly:

blade

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <label for="state_id">State</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Nothing selected" id="state_id" name="state_id">
        @foreach($states as $state)
            <option value="{{ $state->id }}">{{ $state->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <label for="city_id">City</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker"  title="Nothing selected" id="city_id" name="city_id">

    </select>
</div>
```

script

Comment: this can help ? `var newOption = new Option(data.name, data.id, false, false);
select.append(newOption).trigger('change');`

Comment: i have tested both select2 and selectpicker in your script code .it works .can you check for erorr in console

Comment: In which line should I enter these two lines? https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWT3t.png

Comment: I tested it , but it is not working

Comment: I did not any error in console https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je7iY.png

Comment: @irankhostravi first check script is calling or not .better add alert onchange

Comment: Yes, script is calling,

Comment: @irankhostravi check line by line so you can see where it wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234800/discussion-between-irankhostravi-and-john-lobo).